# Display db items in listview android studio

Tags: java, android, database, listview

i am making app with db and i have created db and all things but i cant recive db column items to display it in listview?

here is my dbadapret.java code for displaying only one column from db

```
public Cursor listallbarcodes() {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_CONTAINERBARCODE},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

and here is the code in myactivity for loading this items in list view

```
 private void displayListView() {


    Cursor cursor = myDb.listallbarcodes();

    String[] columns = new String[]{
            DBAdapter.KEY_CONTAINERBARCODE
    };

    int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.product_name,
    };
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mylist, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView_ladung = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_ladung);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView_ladung.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

what do i wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `listallbarcodes` should return a `Cursor` that has one more column: `BaseColumns._ID`

Comment: thanks a lot it work now ! :)